# grunt build getting stuck in running task (ngtemplates:dist)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, gruntjs

This is on an existing project where I have setup npm,bower. "grunt build --force" worked fine in the initial run.

A few days later, with changes in some files (.html, .css, .py) I've been trying to run the "grunt build" / "grunt build --force". After running, the progress is stuck at ""running "ngtemplates:dist" (ngtemplates) task"" and has never ended.

Don't know what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The cause turned out to be an extra double quote symbol in one of the HTML